# child click event firing parent mouseover event

Tags: javascript

I have tree structure in which mouse over on node name displays (UL) list. Each item in the list has a click event attached to it. The issue Im facing is when I click on any child item in list, it fires the mouseover event attached to parent span. Can you guys please help how to solve this issue?

```
<span id="treeNodeText">
<ul><li id="firstItem">First Item</li></ul>
</span>
```

My code is like this:
I have conman event attach method:

```
attachEvents(domId,eventType,callBackFunction,otherParams)
```

In attachEvent function I attach events to dom ids and assign appropriate call back functions

Comment: Hi could you please paste your code

Comment: The mouseover event is fired **before** you click. So, apart with a delay, you can't prevent its handling.

Comment: Why do you put block elements within the inline elements? "Span" is a inline element and "ul" is block element.

Comment: If you have placed `mouseover` event on the parent, it will be fired, when you are accessing child elements. Remove the `mouseover` event if not needed.

Comment: AmGates, Im using span because using DIV is disturbing my css

Comment: @AsadRaza Maybe using DIV is disturbing your css, but using span is still illegal.

Comment: Some more information: when I click on my list item the event.target  shows the correct list id but event.type shows the mouseover event. It means the click event is not fired at all.

Comment: @D3EP4K, thanks for your suggestion. It worked for me. I need to remove mouseover event from parent span when hovering on the list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mouseover` event is fired **before** you click. So, apart with a delay, you can't prevent its handling.

Here's one way to deal with that :

```
var timer;
document.getElementById("treeNodeText").addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
       // handle mouseover
    }, 400); // tune that delay (depending on the sizes of elements, for example)
});
document.getElementById("firstItem").addEventListener('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(timer); // prevents the mouseover event from being handled
    // handle click
};
```

Comment: Jan Dvorak, I need to display the list on hovering on node name. So I need mouse over event.

Comment: Guys, the solution seems to be, as suggested by , D3EP4K, removing mouseover from parent span when hovering on child UL list items. Im generating the list items dynamically on mouseover and when the list is generated and rendered I remove the mouseover event from the span. It ends the scope of mouseover event and the child's click event comes into scope.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, events bubble up the DOM. Please read more about it: [event order and propagation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) or [preventDefault/stopPropagation](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

In short, you can pervent event bubbling by

```
function callBackFunction(event){
  event.stopPropagation()
}
```

or

```
function callBackFunction(event){
  return false
}
```

`return false` also has the effect of preventing the default behavior, so it's technically equivalent to:

```
function callBackFunction(event){
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, as OP wants to prevent mouseover in the parent, not click.

Comment: No,  event.stopPropagation() or returning false is not working. looks like when Im hovering on list items the mouse over event on  "treeNodeText" is still in scope.

Comment: My first link should provide you some insight: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html You might need to rethink some of your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunction(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
 e.preventDefault()
}
```

this will Help