# Links not opening, except when I right click new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a drop down menu to put links in. The links underline properly so I know the a tags are working but when I click on them nothing happens unless I right click and open in new tab. Does anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks!

HTML

```
<div id="dropDown" onmouseover="mouseOver()">\/</div>
```

Javascript

```
function mouseOver()
{
    document.getElementById("dropDown").style.height = "150px";
    document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = "<a href="https://www.google.ca/">foo</a></br>";
    //Other links in list.
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing `</br>` instead of `<br>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you still have the onmouseover event.

Try this:

```
<div id="dropDown" onmouseover="mouseOver()">\/</div>
<script>
function mouseOver()
 {
document.getElementById('dropDown').setAttribute('onmouseover','');
document.getElementById("dropDown").style.height = "150px";
document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = '<a href="https://www.google.ca/">foo</a></br>';
//Other links in list.
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why does the `onmouseover` event handler make the link unclickable?

Comment: it's because the click event is lost when you have the `onmouseover` event because the innerHTML is changed.

Comment: I'd be interested in more information about why replacing the HTML on mouseover destroys the native click event.

Comment: Well, after doing some research I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932550/onmouseover-fired-before-click-and-mouseout-events?answertab=oldest#tab-top) .

Comment: That is interesting, thanks. Also, [child click event firing parent mouseover event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220373/child-click-event-firing-parent-mouseover-event)

Comment: Simply clicking seems to [fire the mouseover event](http://jsfiddle.net/7udxeby3/1/). As an alternative to removing the mouseover event, the mouseenter event [also works](http://jsfiddle.net/7udxeby3/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies within this line of code;

```
document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = "<a href="https://www.google.ca/">foo</a></br>";>
```

Try changing to;

```
document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = "<a href='https://www.google.ca/'>foo</a></br>";>
```

Comment: Fixing the quotes doesn't seem to solve the problem. [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7udxeby3/).